# SQL Server 2008 DBMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to add two column values from two different tables and second table will changed and affects the values in to database.

- First table is `SendStockByVendor`, columns are `product_name`, `Quantity`
- Second table is `presentsupply`, columns are `product_name`, `Quantity`

That two values add and store in 2nd table or in database. But same `product_name` is the condition and remaining values of `presentsuppy` (table name) remain as it is.

I ran the following query but it shows only same name values and quantity but remaining values are not shown.

```
select 
    p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Cost, 
    p.Total_Cost, p.Product_Description, p.Quantity, 
    s.Quantity, 
    p.Quantity + s.Quantity as [Total]
from  
    presentsupply p
join 
    SendStockByVendor s on p.Product_Name = s.Product_Name;
```

Comment: Okay, my eyes crossed by the end ;) Please space out paragraphs and reword so very clear what the expected output is, how each table relates to eachother, and what is actually occuring

Comment: sorry henceforth i will keep this in mind

Comment: Ok - bit of improvement, but not the best (though i guess english skills not that great). Just pls do keep in mind http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Every second you spend improve it is 10 seconds every single other reader doesnt have to re-read to make sense, or just give up and move onto more obvious questions (or downvote in some cases). Btw - i agree (if i understand expected output correctly) that it seems to be issue of left join, please try that and tell us how it works in an edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead to get unmatched `Product`s:

```
SELECT
    p.Product_ID,
    p.Product_Name,
    p.Product_Cost,
    Total_Cost = p.Product_Cost * (p.Quantity + ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0)),
    p.Product_Description,
    p.Quantity,
    s.Quantity,
    p.Quantity + ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0) AS [Total]
FROM 
    presentsupply p
LEFT JOIN 
    SendStockByVendor s ON p.Product_Name = s.Product_Name;
```

Comment: thank you so much but i have one more question i also update total cost column by multiplying product_cost and total in same column?

Comment: See my update: `Total_Cost = p.Product_Cost * (p.Quantity + ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0))`.

Comment: How to store the above query result in new table ?

Comment: Create a `TABLE` first, then use [`INSERT INTO`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT        p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Cost, p.Product_Cost * (p.Quantity + ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0)) AS Total_Cost, p.Product_Description, p.Quantity, 
                         s.Quantity AS Expr1, p.Quantity + ISNULL(s.Quantity, 0) AS Total
FROM            presentsupply AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SendStockByVendor AS s ON p.Product_Name = s.product_name
```

To store into a new table :
Create a table with columns so that you can save the above results.
After that use the below syntax !

`insert into tablename values (above_query)`

Comment: How to store the above query result in new table ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Full outer Join to display all the matched and non matched output**

```
select 
    p.Product_ID, p.Product_Name, p.Product_Cost, 
    p.Total_Cost, p.Product_Description, p.Quantity, 
    s.Quantity, 
    p.Quantity + s.Quantity as [Total]
from  
    presentsupply p
Full Outer join 
    SendStockByVendor s on p.Product_Name = s.Product_Name;
```

Comment: How to store the above query result in new table ?